# Android SQLite Incrementing Integer Field Read from Query

Tags: android, sqlite

Disclosure up front, this is a school project.

I have a method in a class that manages the database for a "quzzer" feature in my app, it is intended to increment (or decrement in one case) three integer fields in an SQLite database. It needs to do this independently from the "quizzing functions", so I need to pull the data first, change it, then update it into the database.

The fields are as follows in the database:
"prof_level" - Only acceptable values are 1 to 4 inclusive.
"times_correct" - Only positive numbers.
"times_incorrect" - Only positive numbers.

I can pull the numbers fine from the db then increment them by 1, but when I update, they increment the values in the db by 2 instead, and I've no idea why. Here is the full code of the method:

```
    public void updateCharacterProf(String table, String charToUpdate, boolean isIncreased){
    //get character from table
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    qb.setTables(table);
    String[] projection = {"prof_level", "times_correct", "times_incorrect"};
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, "character=='" + charToUpdate + "'", null, null, null,
                            null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();

    //check to see if the prof level is at max/min
    int profLevel = c.getInt(0);
    int correctTimes = c.getInt(1);
    int incorrectTimes = c.getInt(2);

    //mod prof levels
    if (isIncreased){
        profLevel++;
        correctTimes++;
    }
    else{
        profLevel--;
        incorrectTimes++;
    }

    if (profLevel == 4 && isIncreased){
        profLevel = 4;
    }
    else if (profLevel == 1 && !isIncreased){
        profLevel = 1;
    }

    c.close();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("prof_level", profLevel);
    values.put("times_correct", correctTimes);
    values.put("times_incorrect", incorrectTimes);

    //update db
    db.update(table, values, "character=='" + charToUpdate + "'", null);

    db.close();
}
```

I'm hoping that it's just something I don't get about how updating SQLite dbs, but I'm lost at the "var++ == +=2" thing that I'm getting now.

Comment: You attempts to keep `profLevel` in the 1..4 range do not work, but the code to increase the other variables looks OK, as long as this function is called a single time.

Comment: Yeah, I saw how that didn't work and changed it to a "if profvalue >= 4 then profvalue = 4"  type structure.

Comment: As for amount of calls, it's called in a loop, but with different parameters each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the issue was o e of my own creation, I fired the callback that calls this database update twice accidently in the dialog fragment that calls it (once in an onClick method and once in a life cycle onDismiss override.).

Fixing this bug, which happened during another different dateabase related thing, fixed the problem for me.